# How to update existing job firing time?

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, cronexpression

I have created a list of job which is executing as per there schedule time but what i need to do if job schedule time is changed so how the scheduled job's firing time will get changed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to reschedule the job with a new trigger that has the new fire times you want. It's not possible to update a trigger's fire times. How to do this depends on the version of Quartz.Net you're running, as the API has changed significantly between V1 and V2

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reschedule the
job with a new trigger that has
the new fire times you want. It's
not possible to update a trigger's
fire times. How to do this
depends on the version of
Quartz.Net you're running, as the
API has changed significantly
between V1 and V2